# Convert String to a DateTime Format (GMT) - Return type should be in Date time

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

I have a string with Date time format **'10-12-2022 08:00 AM'** I am trying to convert this string to DateTime format (GMT). **2022-10-12T12:00:00Z** (Return Type should be DateTime, not the String)

**Method 1:**

```
String jsonDate ='10-12-2022 08:00 AM';
String effDate = jsonDate.replace('-','/');
DateTime tempDate = DateTime.parse(effDate);
System.debug('Formatted date: ' + tempDate.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z');
```

**Method 2:**

```
String jsonDate ='10-12-2022 08:00 AM';
String effDate = jsonDate.replace('-','/');
DateTime tempDate = DateTime.parse(effDate);
system.debug('tempDate'+tempDate);
String convertedDate = tempDate.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
system.debug('convertedDate'+convertedDate);
DateTime result = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"'+convertedDate+'"', DateTime.class);
system.debug(result);
```

**Reason for doing it**: I need to pass this DateTime to SOQL Query to filter the records

I have tried different methods to achieve this, but of no use. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can avoid formatting on JS side, just pass milliseconds:

```
let dateInMilis = new Date('10-12-2022 08:00 AM').getTime(); // 1665550800000
```

And then on Apex side do:

```
Datetime datetimeNeeded = Datetime.newInstance(dateImMilis);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I am not using Js as it's not an LWC.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using only Date.parse method and passing it to the query to get the records.